# How to change legend labels in ggplot2 for visualizing data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am using ggplot2 to visualize some data in R.

Therefore I use the following command:

```
ggplot(second_sentiment_counts)+
  aes(x = sentiment, y = n, fill = as.factor(sentiment)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(title = "Deep Learning\nSentiment Analysis Results using RNTN",
       x = "Sentiments",
       y = "Occurences") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkred", "red4", "blue", "green4", "darkgreen"),
                    name = "Sentiment\nValues")
```

This gives me the following plot:[image]

However, I would like to change the legend labels, so that "-1" is "very negative" or "+1" is "very positive".

Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: use `labels` to set it manually... `scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkred","red4","blue","green4","darkgreen"), labels = c("very negative", "kinda negative", "neutral", "kinda positive", "very positive"), name="Sentiment\nValues")`

Comment: wonderful, thank you very much it worked really well! :)

Comment: adding to the great comment by @Nate, you must change the `scale_` according to your aesthetic. E.g. if you use `aes(color = as.factor(sentiment))` instead of `aes(fill = as.factor(sentiment))`, then you must use `scale_color_manual` instead of `scale_fill_manual`